# Copying an upper part of a string only

Tags: trim

I am new in C and I am trying to copy an upper part of a string like for example the string is "Let's go to the mall". I would like to place only "Let's go to the" to a newly allocated pointer then later on concatenate it with something else. Can someone suggest how I could implement this?

I am thinking of something like this:

```
char *sample = "Let's go to the mall";
char *lower_half = " club and dance";
char *upper_half = malloc(sizeof(sample) + sizeof(lower_half));

strcpy(upper_half,sample);       <<<<------- How can i copy the "Let's go to the"?
strcat(upper_half,lower_half);

printf("String:%s\n",upper_half);
```

Then the result would be "Let's go to the club and dance".

I am also not sure if my allocation for upper_half is right. Is it too large?

Comment: consider using `memcpy()`.

Comment: Do you get an error at strcpy(); ?

Comment: I tried memcpy but it gets corrupted when I use strcpy and strcat routines on different strings.

Comment: There's no error on strcpy, the thing is, the whole string is being copied but I just want the upper half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
  strncpy(upper_half,sample,15);      // with last parameter, number of char to copy.
  strcat(upper_half,lower_half);
```